# How to reinstall Ubuntu without lose Home Information

Tags: system-installation

I reinstall Ubuntu, and in partitioning remove root and create new root and install, after install my home information goto a new volume mounted and my home empty and my home capacity equal with root. ?
how to change to back, and create home and transform information to home ?

Answer (score 0):

You may try [TestDisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk) to recover lost partitions. It won't help at all, it you have already rewrote the partition... if you just modified the partition table, it will help.

### Backup is important

You just need to back up (copy to an external location) your `/home/YOUR_USERNAME` directory, then restore it back.
You can use a simple USB stick (but don't think that that is a forever lasting one). Very important data should be backed up regularly, etc... I'm using Cloud for example ([Google Drive](http://drive.google.com), [Dropbox](https://db.tt/wiaI5oM), ...)

If you need further help, refer to this documentation: [HomeFolder](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HomeFolder) or [BackupYourSystem](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BackupYourSystem).

Answer (score 0):

First you mount your old /home to some safe mount point (e.g. /media/old_home) to check if the new installations user and group file system permissions are consistent with the user those of your old /home
If this is the case you need to edit /etc/fstab to mount it automatically at boot time as /home.
If you have anything of value on the new installations /home (in the / partition - as soon you mount something else to /home it will still be on the disk but not accessible) make a backup and copy it later on to your /home

see: 
man fstab
man mount
about file system permissions also see: 
/etc/passwd
/etc/groups